# prevent image overlap with css grid

Tags: css

I am almost done with a landing page of a fictional travel agency. I decided to add images and my idea is to have one image to the left and text to the right, The second image to the right and text to the left, and the third image to take up the full width of available space and text below it.

I have tried using a CSS grid to try to accomplish it but nothing, I also checked the internet, and nothing. The issue I run into is that the second and third images overlap one another. my code is below.
The HTML and CSS are below. p.s. what I mean by nothing is that any type of possible answers I may find on the internet won't work, I still get my last two images overlapping instead of the pattern I want.

```
 .mid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "intro intro" "pic1 title1" "title2 pic2" "pic3 pic3" "title3 title3" "pend pend";
  }

  .mid .mid-intro {
    grid-area: intro;
  }

  .mid .pic-1 {
    grid-area: pic1;
  }

  .mid .pic-1-title {
    grid-area: title1;
  }

  .mid .pic-2 {
    grid-area: pic2;
  }

  .mid .pic-2-title {
    grid-area: title2;
  }

  .mid .pic-3 {
    grid-area: pic3;
  }

  .mid .pic-3-title {
    grid-area: title3;
  }

  .mid .p-end {
    grid-area: pend;
  }



<section class="mid">
       <p class="mid-intro">Our mission is for your trip to be an enjoyable one.</p>
       
           <img src="img/img-1.jpg" alt="" class="pic-1">
           <p class="pic-1-title">Spend time with family</p>
           <img src="img/img-2.jpg" alt="" class="pic-2">
           <p class="pic-2-title">Create memories that will be remembered for ever.</p>
           <img src="img/img-3.jpg" alt="" class="pic-2">
           <p class="pic-3-title">Have fun</p>
       <p class="p-end">May the adventure begin.</p>

   </section>
```

Comment: Please could you give more detail of what is going wrong - what is 'nothing'. Please also add HTML to you question so we can run the snippet and see the problem for ourselves. you hvae defined title3 but are invoking title-3.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed `p` to `div`. Also the images are now in div containers:

```css
.mid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 10px;
}
.mid-intro {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
.p-end {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}

.mid div {
    background: red
}
```

```html
<section class="mid">
            <div class="mid-intro">Our mission is for your trip to be an enjoyable one.</div>
            
           <div><img src="img/img-1.jpg" alt="img1" class="pic-1"></div>
           <div class="pic-1-title">Spend time with family</div>
           
           <div class="pic-2-title">Create memories that will be remembered for ever.</div>
           <div><img src="img/img-2.jpg" alt="img2" class="pic-2"></div>
           
           <div><img src="img/img-3.jpg" alt="img3" class="pic-2"></div>
           <div class="pic-3-title">Have fun</div>
           
            <div class="p-end">May the adventure begin.</div>

</section>
```